# Integrating $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble evaluating this integral:

$$I = \int \frac{1}{1+e^x} dx$$

I tried rearranging and then making a substitution as follows:

$$I = \int 1 - \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} dx$$

Let $$u = 1+e^x$$ then $$du = e^x dx$$

$$\therefore I = \int 1 - \frac{1}{1+u} du$$

$$ = u - \ln (1+u) +c$$
$$ = 1+e^x - \ln (1+e^x) +c$$

However, the answers suggest it should be $x - \ln(1+e^x)$. I've been combing through my work but can't figure out where I've gone wrong. What's wrong with my integration?

Comment: the first is $\int 1 \, dx$ not $\int 1 \, du.$

Comment: Alternatively, you may use the fact that $\frac{1}{1+e^x} = \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$ and find a primitive for the right hand side.

Comment: You mean $u = e^x$, I think, not $u = 1 + e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\int 1 dx - \int \frac{1}{1+u}du
$$
since you had
$$
\int 1 -\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{1+\mathrm{e}^x}dx
$$
then made the sub $u = \mathrm{e}^x\implies du = \mathrm{e}^xdx$ so your integral should be
$$
\int \frac{1}{u}du - \int \frac{1}{1+u}du
$$
$\textbf{edit}$
lets go from your method $u = 1+\mathrm{e}^x$ then we have
$$
\int \frac{1}{u-1} - \frac{1}{u}du \neq \int 1 du -\int \frac{1}{1+u}du
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see the solution now. However I would appreciate it if you could explain why my working doesn't work. I can't see the mathematical issue with it

Comment: The problem is you have $(1 - \frac{e^{x}}{1 + e^{x}})dx$. Then you do the $u$ substitution, and get $(1 - \frac{e^{x}}{1 + u})\frac{du}{e^{x}}$. You wrote this as $(1 - \frac{1}{1 + u})du$, but you neglected the fact that the $e^{x}$ distributes over both terms.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+e^x}=\int\frac{e^{-x}\,dx}{e^{-x}+1}=-\ln(e^{-x}+1).$$

---

If you want, this can be rewritten
$$-\ln(e^{-x}+1)=-\ln\left(e^{-x}(1+e^x)\right)=x-\ln(1+e^x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Now here is an easier way $$I = \int \frac{1}{1 + e^x} dx$$

Now let $u = 1 + e^x$ and so $e^x = u-1$ and also $du = e^xdx \implies dx = \frac{du}{e^x}$ and so your integral becomes

$$I = \int \frac{1}{u} \times \frac{du}{e^x}$$ but notice that we have $e^x = u -1$ and so we have $$I = \int \frac{1}{u (u-1)} du$$ Now can you do this integral ?

It is easy because $$\frac{1}{u(u+1)} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u+1}$$ and your integral becomes $$I = \int \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u+1} du$$ which is simply $$I = ln(u) - ln(u+1)$$ .

Now $u = 1 + e^x$ and $u+1 = 2 + e^x$ and so $$I = ln(1+e^x) - ln(2 + e^x)$$